# Vuepress: How can I switch config.js depending deploy target?

Tags: vuepress

How can I switch config.js depending on the target?
For example, in case deploy to localhost, I'd set **dest:** parameter in config.js as **public**:

```
dest: 'public/docs'
```

or, as **dist** for **netlify**

```
dest: 'dist/docs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution with vuepress 1.x as --dest option, like as follows:

```
vuepress build --dest dist/docs docs
```

The docs is created on dist folder even config.js specifies as `dest: 'public/docs',`